# JSP <c:out/> - The default attribute doesn't work?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm having trouble with the default attribute of the JSP/JSTL tag . The value given for the default-attribute is not displayed.

```
<% @ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:out value='value' default="defaultValue"/>
```

=> Displays value

```
<c:out value='' default="defaultValue"/>
```

=> Displays nothing.. // Should have been `defaultValue`

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you'd better use double-quotes (`"`).

Then, `""` *is* a value - it is an empty string. The default value is used when the value is `null`